# Using custom data files in an android app

Tags: java, android, class, file-io

I am a fairly good java programmer and am now tackling android app development using the android sdk.  I am creating a reader app using java that uses custom java classes to store the reading material. In a normal java program I could save these files to a .dat file as a single array of objects and access them later with a single import command.  Is there a way to do this for an android application? I have already built a program that saves the data as a .dat file.  I would like to include that file in my application and import it when the app starts up.

Comment: yes you can. just do the same way as java. the only difference is where you save the file? in asset or SD card?

Comment: As an asset. Where in the file structure would I place it?  I am working in eclipse and want the file to be packaged within the app.